# Button in UserControl in main page not reacting to pointer in Windows Store apps

Tags: xaml, user-controls, windows-store-apps

To share a common display layout in a Split template Windows Store app, I put a Back button, title TextBlock, and another button in a UserControl, and then use that control in most of my pages.  My problem is that in the main page, neither of the buttons will react to pointer activity, be it pointer over or clicking.  However, it works fine in any other page.  To isolate it, I created a blank app and duplicated the UserControl, but it works in that case.

How can I debug this?

Thanks.

-John

Comment: There must be something in your main page that is breaking it. Try comparing it with the other pages. If that doesn't help try removing stuff from it until it starts working. Or start recreating the functionality in a new page until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

In an "ItemView" page of a "Split" template app, the Grid containing the back button and title must be below the GridView and ListView in the XAML code.  Apparently the GridView, with no Grid.Row, and a Grid.RowSpan="2" needs to overlay the first and second rows, and if the button is beneath the GridView, it must assume it is not visible and doesn't need to respond to events.  I moved my new user control instance to below the GridView, and the buttons work now.

This whole scheme of overlaying both rows makes no sense to me, but without the Grid.RowSpan="2", the items don't split nicely into two rows for me.  I think such odd layout should have a comment explaining it in the template.  Perhaps it could save someone else from this same kind of issue.